# Rewrites, redirects and headers not working when deploying a NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js

I'm trying to redirect the user when entering manually the URL, here's the `next.config.js` file structure:

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/BookManagement',
  reactStrictMode: true,

  redirects: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/books',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/book',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Everything works as expected in the local env, but when deploying using Azure DevOps, it doesn't having this error code:

```
warn  - rewrites, redirects, and headers are not applied when exporting your application, detected (redirects). See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-no-custom-routes
```

Any idea how can I use `rewrites` and `redirects` ?

Comment: It looks like you're exporting your Next.js as static HTML with `next export`, which doesn't support `redirects`/`rewrites` - https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features. You'll probably need to handle it in Azure DevOps directly.

Comment: I've tried handling it on Azure DevOps in `ingress.yaml` ,  but it breaks the NextJS rendering. What do you think about changing build type, like changing Dockerfile or is there any way to export as static HTML without `next export`?

Comment: If you want your Next.js app exported as static HTML you have to use `next export`. _"I've tried handling it on Azure DevOps in ingress.yaml , but it breaks the NextJS rendering"_ - Can you provide more details? How does it break rendering exactly?

Comment: Here is my `ingress.yaml` file: https://ctxt.io/2/AADgXjZTEw
Although I'm using a configuration like this: 
` nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: >
      rewrite /books  https://hostname.com/BooksManagement
      permanent;` 
When typing  https://hostname.com/BooksManagement/books, it will redirect me to https://hostname.com/BooksManagement/books# and I have to click twice on every element twice in order to make the events working.
Any idea about `ingress.yaml` configuration when having 3 pages: home ("/"), books "/books") and book ("/book")

Comment: Could you please add all that extra information to the question?

Comment: Yes, the error that I'm getting is the following: ` 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at books-d12eb5cfb71e603a.js:1:1)
main-d235d0beb690ca5b.js:1 Error: Route did not complete loading: /books`